# Is it possible to limit the fields you can filter on list views?

Tags: list-view, filters, field-level-security

I ran into a very basic request at first that now I am struggling with, so hope to get my curiosity cleared with this query:

- I've limited the user's profile visibility in the `Campaign` object to not have access to any fields.
- Via a permission set, I've given access to just a few fields on the `Campaign` object.
- When I want to add some filters on a custom List View I still see **all** the fields of the `Campaign` object, even though for the majority of them, in theory, the user shouldn't have access.

**Q 1:** Shouldn't the field level security restrict the fields you can choose to filter on a list view?

**Q 2:** If that's not the case, then how can we limit the number of these fields? For the end user this can become pretty cumbersome to use and navigate through an exhaustive list of fields, that potentially they're aware/need only a few of them.

[image]

Comment: Is the above list when you're logged in as the user? Or when logged in as sysad?

Comment: As the actual (restricted) user

Comment: does the restricted user have Customize Application permission?

Comment: Nope - neither from the profile, nor from the perm sets.